# Add all vertexes X & Y value to attribute table

Tags: arcpy, vertices

Is it possible to automatically extract every pair of (X,Y) coordinates of every vertices for a polygon and add it to its attribute table?

For example: if a polygon has 7 vertices I want 14 new fields in the attribute table: X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4.....
Or if it has 4 vertices I want the fields X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4 to contain their coordinates and the other ones (X5,Y5,X6,Y6....) to be empty.

Is there a tool / script that does such a thing?

Comment: Do you have a known limit on the number of vertices? Otherwise, you might end up with a very large attribute table. Are you trying to export the polygons in order to put them into a csv or Excel table?

Comment: I could add a limit to the number of vertices, that would be no problem, and yes, I want them for an Excel table which would contain all the attributes and every (X,Y) pair of coordinates.

Comment: Please do not ask Boolean questions, especially "Is it possible" questions (for which the answer is nearly always "Yes") in GIS SE.  It is generally unwise to add scores of fields to tables when there are generally limitations to the number of fields per table.  Best practice would be to create a normalized table with {feature,seq,xval,yval}.  Either is certainly possible, but GIS SE policy with scripting is for the question to include best effort at coding.

Comment: Completely agreeing with @Vince, I would like to ask what is your purpose of asking this since there might be better approaches to your problem. Again the fields are rather valuable entities to consume as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I have the following script that basically does what @Vince suggests in creating a table of features, parts, coordinates.  You may be able to make use of this by pulling the output into Excel and joining to your data with the structure you require.

The output ends up looking like:

[image]

for features that look like:

[image]

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

featureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Feature Class to Inspect
newTableParam = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Table to save feature vertex info

# Create new table
newTablePath, newTableName = os.path.split(newTableParam)
arcpy.CreateTable_management(newTablePath, newTableName)
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'FeatureOID', 'LONG')
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'PartNumber', 'SHORT')
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'DonutHoleNumber', 'SHORT')
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'PointNumber', 'SHORT')
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'XCoord', 'DOUBLE', 15, 5)
arcpy.AddField_management(newTableParam, 'YCoord', 'DOUBLE', 15, 5)

geomType = arcpy.Describe(featureClass).shapeType

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newTableParam, ['FeatureOID', 'PartNumber', 'DonutHoleNumber', 'PointNumber', 'XCoord', 'YCoord']) as iCursor:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featureClass, ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', 'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            partNumber = 0 # Reset the count
            donutHoleNumber = 0 # Reset the count
            pointNumber = 0 # Reset the count

            # If input is point FC then get XY values from each point
            if geomType == 'Point': 
                newRow = (row[0], partNumber, donutHoleNumber, pointNumber, row[2][0], row[2][1])
                iCursor.insertRow(newRow) # Add the details to the table

            # Otherwise iterate through each part (Multipoint, Polyline, Polygon)
            else:
                for part in row[1]:
                    pointNumber = 0 # Restart the count for new parts
                    donutHoleNumber = 0 # Restart the count for new parts

                    # If input is multipoint then get XY values for each part of the multipoint feature
                    if geomType == 'Multipoint':
                        newRow = (row[0], partNumber, donutHoleNumber, pointNumber, part.X, part.Y)
                        iCursor.insertRow(newRow) # Add the details to the table
                        pointNumber += 1 # Add to the count

                    # Otherwise iterate through each vertex of each part (Polyline, Polygon)
                    else:
                        for point in part:
                            # Iterate through each vertex and get XY values
                            if point:
                                newRow = (row[0], partNumber, donutHoleNumber, pointNumber, point.X, point.Y)
                                iCursor.insertRow(newRow) # Add the details to the table
                                pointNumber += 1 # Add to the count

                            # A Null point indicates a new section of the part - usually a donut hole inside the polygon
                            else:
                                donutHoleNumber += 1 # Add to the count
                                pointNumber = 0 # Restart the numbering to count each vertex of the donut hole

                    partNumber += 1 # Add to the count
```

Credit: This code was based on the sample code from [Reading Geometries (ArcGIS Desktop Help)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/reading-geometries.htm)